# merging 2 partially matching rows python

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently trying to construct a dataframe from multiple sources using pandas. I am having the issue that I am unable to merge two rows within a dataframe that are partially matching. The example:

input:

```
|String  |  A  |  B  |  C  |
|--------------------------|
|Hey     |  1  | NaN |  2  |
|Bye     |  1  |  2  |  3  |
|Hey     | NaN |  5  | NaN |
```

wanted output:

```
|String  |  A  |  B  |  C  |
|--------------------------|
|Hey     |  1  |  5  |  2  |
|Bye     |  1  |  2  |  3  |
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the `join` function is what you're looking for: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC need [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df = df.groupby('String', sort=False, as_index=False).first()
print (df)
  String    A    B    C
0    Hey  1.0  5.0  2.0
1    Bye  1.0  2.0  3.0
```

Comment: Perfect, Cheers